# Stack Exchange user flair on LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin, stack-exchange

Is there any way to add the [Stack Exchange user flair](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/flair/info) on a LinkedIn profile?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22716/is-it-possible-to-show-the-stack-exchange-flair-on-linkedin

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a Stack Exchange support issue. Such questions should be asked at [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Edit Profile`->`Background`, you can add an image URL in stack exchange's user flair from the icon the top right. The image would arrange in two columns so there spacing as the flairs are small but it looks ok with title and description.